# A strong upper bound for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm proving that the sequence $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log{n}}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$.

I will like to find a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log{n}} < \epsilon$. For this I need a strong upper bound for the terms. I think $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is the strongest. Is that ok?

Kind regards,

Comment: You don't need a strong upper bound for such proofs that's one of the fundamental features of an $\epsilon-N$ proof. There are infinitely many choices for $\epsilon$ and you have suggested a valid method to obtain one.

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your  bound suffices for proving  limit is $0$

$$\sqrt{n} < \sqrt{n} \log n \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log n}$$
and to prove limit $|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n} \log n}| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon$

then for $n> \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$ suffices .